# Biblatex: Inconsistent citation format

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

I am using same format of .bib file entry, but get different output formats in beamer. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Trial frame}
\cite{Borzacchiello2017} \\
\cite{LEGUENNEC2018} \\
\cite{Goldfarb2014} \\
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with the following .bib file entries:

```
@article{LEGUENNEC2018,
    author = "Le Guennec, Yves 
         and Brunet, Jean-Patrick 
         and Daim, Fatima Zohra 
         and Chau, Ming 
         and Tourbier, Yves",
    title = "A parametric and non-intrusive reduced order model of car crash simulation",
    journal = "Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering",
    year = "2018",
}

@Article{Borzacchiello2017,
    author="Borzacchiello, Domenico
        and Aguado, Jos{\'e} V.
        and Chinesta, Francisco",
    title="Non-intrusive Sparse Subspace Learning for Parametrized Problems",
    journal="Archives of Computational Methods in Engineering",
    year = "2017",
}

@article{Goldfarb2014,
    author = "Goldfarb, Donald and Qin, Zhiwei",
    title = "Robust Low-Rank Tensor Recovery: Models and Algorithms",
    journal = "SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications",
    year = "2014",
}
```

But I get the following output. As you can see the format is different in reference slide and citation as well:

[image]

I would like to have:

1) citation format : "FirstAuthor Year", preferably without "et. al"

2) Reference slide format: names of all authors, with first names abbreviated

Comment: Can you explicitly list what you'd like to change?

Comment: Check maxnames in the documentation.

Comment: It's not "inconsistent", it is a feature. `biblatex` controls, according to the number of authors, whether the list should be shortened or not. This is configurable. What is the behavior you'd like to obtain?

Comment: I would like the format "FirstAuthorName year", instead of "et al" in one place and list of authors in other. Also, for references, it would be cool if first names are abbreviated in references

Comment: @KiranSagar You mean that any which is not the first author should be put under "et al."? If so, you can follow Ulrike's advice, and use `maxnames=1` in your biblatex's options. If you want all names to appear always `maxnames=99` should be enough.

Comment: But I would all authors to be listed in references, with first names abbreviated

Comment: And cite using "FirstAuthorName Year" format

Comment: Please, state clearly, in your question, what is the result you'd like to obtain. This can be controlled independently for citations and bibliography, if need be.

Comment: included requirements in the question

Comment: Please, specify one further thing. In the citation, the other authors which are not the first should simply not be presented, not even under an "et al."? (This may be confusing to the reader)

Comment: preferably,  "et al" should not be used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To control the namelists according to your specifications, `biblatex`'s package options are enough. `maxcitenames=1` will give citations with only the first author (regularly, with "et al."); `maxbibnames=99` should be enough for normal cases to include all authors in the bibliography; `giveninits=true` will abbreviate given names throughout.

To remove the "et al." of shortened authors lists a simple solution is to redefine the corresponding localization string with:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={}}
```

Indeed, since version 3.13, `biblatex` offers support to this procedure. In particular, you should use `nohashothers=true` when removing the "et al." string to allow `biblatex` to generate unique labels for your citations. You can also fine-tune sorting in this case with the option `nosortothers`.

I'm personally not keen on removing the "et al." string, and I don't recommend it, but a recent version of `biblatex` allows you to do so, if you really wish, in a consistent manner.

Note I have changed your `style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear` to `style=authoryear`. Mixing those styles, though technically "works", is bound to give you some inconsistencies or sub optimal results.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
  @article{LEGUENNEC2018,
    author = "Le Guennec, Yves
              and Brunet, Jean-Patrick
              and Daim, Fatima Zohra
              and Chau, Ming
              and Tourbier, Yves",
    title = "A parametric and non-intrusive reduced order model of car crash simulation",
    journal = "Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering",
    year = "2018",
  }

  @article{LEGUENNEC2018_2,
    author = "Le Guennec, Yves",
    title = "Study 2 by le Guennec",
    journal = "A journal title",
    year = "2018",
  }

  @Article{Borzacchiello2017,
    author="Borzacchiello, Domenico
            and Aguado, Jos{\'e} V.
            and Chinesta, Francisco",
    title="Non-intrusive Sparse Subspace Learning for Parametrized Problems",
    journal="Archives of Computational Methods in Engineering",
    year = "2017",
  }

  @article{Goldfarb2014,
    author = "Goldfarb, Donald and Qin, Zhiwei",
    title = "Robust Low-Rank Tensor Recovery: Models and Algorithms",
    journal = "SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications",
    year = "2014",
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  maxcitenames=1,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  nohashothers=true,
  nosortothers=true,
  ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Trial frame}
  \cite{Borzacchiello2017}

  \cite{LEGUENNEC2018}

  \cite{LEGUENNEC2018_2}

  \cite{Goldfarb2014}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in citations:

[image]

and references:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm, but had to I include ``uniquename=init`` in one of the options to avoid warnings about conflicting options.

Comment: I opened a feature request to discuss ways to properly discard the "et al.": https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861

Comment: @moewe I was aware of `ext-authoryear-terse` naturaly. Still, it is a different kind of "terse", ain't it?

Comment: Sure. but you know me, I can't let an opportunity to advertise `biblatex-ext` slide ;-)

Comment: @moewe Fair enough!

Comment: Since 3.13 with the ability to suppress "et al." properly is out now, would you mind updating your answer accordingly?

Comment: @moewe Not at all. Done! (Let me know if I missed something, I might well have, as the issue is somewhat scattered in discussion and commits).

Comment: @moewe And I take the opportunity to congratulate and thank you for the new release. Plenty of goodies there! Particularly, the new option handling structure is major. Outstanding job overall. Thank you very, very much. For the new release and the great work that is being done there in general. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the update. Thanks also for the kind words.